# react set component props programaytically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set an react (v15) component its props callback function dynamically somehow. Something like below, bud it isn't working as I wanted it to be.

The whole idea behind this is that the popup needs to return specific data for an grid item that is pressed specifically in the grid (html table).

Any suggestions how to archive this dynamic setting of a component and its props?

The code below gives this error:

`TypeError: can't define property "dynamicCallback": Object is not extensible`

(I guess the element props is set with [Object.preventExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible))

```
getGridColumnData() {
    var notificationsColumnsObj = columns.GridData; // from json file, Array With columns

        for (let iColumn = 0; iColumn < notificationsColumnsObj.length; iColumn++) {
            if (notificationsColumnsObj[iColumn].field === 'Landlord_Name') {
                notificationsColumnsObj[iColumn]['editor'] = function (container, options) {

                    that.refs.searchCompanyPopup.props.dynamicCallback = function (data) {
                        var landlordName = null;
                        var landlordCode = null;
                        if (data) {
                            landlordCode = data.Code;
                            landlordName = data.Name;
                        }
                        options.model.set('Landlord_Code', landlordCode);
                        options.model.set('Landlord_Name', landlordCode);
                    };
                };
            }
        }
    return notificationsColumnsObj;
}
<SearchPopup ref="searchPopup" data={this.state.data} />
```

**-**

**Update**

How I managed to tet it working in the end. I used the state to set the function used for the callback by the popup. When you click an item in the grid: notificationsColumnsObj[iColumn]['editor'] is called, then the state is set for the popup callback when it finishes to call the function.

```
var that;
class TheComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props,context) {
        super(props,context);
        this.state={
            data: {},
            landlordSelectedCallback: function (data) {},
        }
        that = this;
    }

    getGridColumnData() {
    var notificationsColumnsObj = columns.GridData; // from json file, Array With columns

        for (let iColumn = 0; iColumn < notificationsColumnsObj.length; iColumn++) {
            //only one item will match this, not multiple
            if (notificationsColumnsObj[iColumn].field === 'Landlord_Name') {
                notificationsColumnsObj[iColumn]['editor'] = function (container, options) {
                    that.setState({
                        landlordSelectedCallback: function (data) {
                            var landlordName = null;
                            var landlordCode = null;
                            if (data) {
                                landlordCode = data.Code;
                                landlordName = data.Name;
                            }
                            options.model.set('Landlord_Code', landlordCode);
                            options.model.set('Landlord_Name', landlordCode);
                        }
                    }, () => { //callback function, after the state is set
                        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that.refs.searchPopup)).modal(); //shows the <SearchPopup modal

                        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that.refs.searchPopup)).off('hide.bs.modal');
                        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that.refs.searchPopup)).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                            $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that.refs.searchPopup)).off('hide.bs.modal');
                            that.closeGridCellFromEditing(); //closes the grid cell edit mode
                        });
                    });
                };
            }
        }
        return notificationsColumnsObj;
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>[other nodes]
                    <SearchPopup ref="searchPopup" data={this.state.data} onModalFinished={this.state.landlordSelectedCallback} />
                </div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that what your trying to do is anti pattern, my suggestion is to keep the props you want in parent component state and simply pass them to child component and whenever you wanted to update them setState on parent component

Comment: Why not to just pass this callback function to your component ? Is something that I'm missing ?

Comment: Yes, its a bit more complex, I updated the question a bit, to explain some more

Comment: You still haven't explained why you cannot pass the function as a prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working for two reasons:

1. Because your ref is called `searchPopup`, not `props`. Per [the documentation for legacy string `refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs), you would access that via `this.refs.searchProps`.
2. Because [props are read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only).

I'm a bit surprised that the second rule is actively enforced, but that's a good thing. :-)

If you want to change the props of a child component, you do so by changing your state such that you re-render the child with the new props. This is part of React's [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) / [Data Flows Down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down) philosophy(ies).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than feeding a new callback function, just keep one function but feed data to it.

```
getGridColumnData() {
    var notificationsColumnsObj = columns.GridData; //from json file, Array With columns

        for (let iColumn = 0; iColumn < notificationsColumnsObj.length; iColumn++) {
            if (notificationsColumnsObj[iColumn].field === 'Landlord_Name') {
                notificationsColumnsObj[iColumn]['editor'] = (function (container, options) {
                    this.options = options
                }).bind(this);
            }
        }
    return notificationsColumnsObj;
}

dynamicCallback = function (data) {
  var landlordName = null;
  var landlordCode = null;
  if (data) {
    landlordCode = data.Code;
    landlordName = data.Name;
  }
  this.options.model.set('Landlord_Code', landlordCode);
  this.options.model.set('Landlord_Name', landlordCode);
}

render() {
  return <SearchPopup ref="searchPopup" data={this.state.data} dynamicCallback = {this.dynamicCallback.bind(this)}/>
}
```